# Node child_process mute, read and handle children logs within parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a parent script that spawns children nodes.

```
let child = child_process.fork('foo.js', ['param1', param2])
child.on('message', data => {
//  console.log(data);
})
child.on('exit', code => {
  resolve(true)
})
```

Originally I thought that `child.on('message')` event listener catches and handles message but that's not the case here. Children simply uses parent `process.stdout.write` function and log stuff to parent console by default.

- Is there a way to read these logs and parse them within parent?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options .fork should act like .spawn, and you can use the stdio option to lift up the stdout to the parent. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdio

Comment: @rlemon I tried that but I failed to understand which event listener should parent use to fetch log data

Comment: check out this overly simplified example: https://gist.github.com/rlemon/eb2cbb00bf557f0d2d54801d54a89984 - if that doesn't help I'm probably completely misunderstanding what your intent is

Comment: @rlemon Thank you for this Gist, but it returns error which I added in comment to gist due to SO comment limitation. Basically error says it requires IPC channel as one of fields in array. I am using node version 6.9.1

Comment: weird. works for me. node v6.1.0

Comment: @rlemon Just switched version to 6.1.0 and it doesn't show this error anymore. However, I still fail to understand which event listener should I use to assign these logs to variable. `process.stdout.on('data', data => {
      console.log('data', data);
    })`

Comment: you can set silent to true on the child fork and listen for the stdout pipe. `fork('./foo.js',{silent: true}).stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data));`

Comment: `child.stdout.on('data', data => {
      console.log(data)
    })` returns Buffer. Using `readline` module converted it to string lines. Can we create answer out of this? The node.js version issue kinda troubles me. Should an issue be posted? Is it changed in newer version with reason? How to solve this problem in newer versions?

Comment: you don't need readline. you can call .toString('utf-8') on a buffer (or just .toString()) to get the string results.

Comment: @rlemon That's even better! Btw, after changing params object to `{silent:true}` and switching back to `6.9.1` the error related to `IPC` is no longer present. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set silent to true on the child fork and listen for the stdout pipe.

```
fork('./foo.js',{silent: true})
    .stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
```